# Java8 lambda two collections substract

Tags: java

DTO

```java
public class Result {
    private List<Module> modules;
}

public class Module {
    private String name;
    private List<TestCase> testCases;
}

public class TestCase {
    private String name;
    private String result;
}
```

Suppose I have two Items,

```xml
<!-- Result1 -->
<Result>
    <Module name="a">
        <TestCase name="tc1" result="pass"/>
        <TestCase name="tc2" result="pass"/>
    </Module>
    <Module name="b">
        <TestCase name="tc1" result="pass"/>
        <TestCase name="tc2" result="pass"/>
        <TestCase name="tc3" result="pass"/>
    </Module>
</Result>

<!-- Result2 -->
<Result>
    <Module name="a">
        <TestCase name="tc1" result="pass"/>
    </Module>
</Result>
```

I want to get intersection of two sets Result1 and Result2

(for example **result1.intersection(result2)**)

**Result**

```xml
<Result>
    <Module name="a">
        <TestCase name="tc2" result="pass"/>
    </Module>
    <Module name="b">
        <TestCase name="tc1" result="pass"/>
        <TestCase name="tc2" result="pass"/>
        <TestCase name="tc3" result="pass"/>
    </Module>
</Result>
```

I know how to intersect the two collections. but, if collections of collections is exists, I don't know how to intersect the collections.

How to do this using java 8 streams? or other way?

Comment: Why would `Module name="c"` be in the output? It's not in `Result1`.

Comment: Can you show the code which you have tried so far?

Comment: @Eran oh, my mistake... I corrected the result.

Answer (score 0):

You should implement equals method for your Module class then you can use a method similar this one :

```
public Result intersection(Result r1, Result r2) {
    Result result = new Result();

    r1.getModules().forEach(module -> {
      if (r2.getModules().contains(module)) {
        result.getModules().add(module);
      }
    });
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java 8 code to find intersection

```
Set<Result> result = list.stream()
  .distinct()
  .filter(otherList::contains)
  .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Since `Result` is a custom class, for the intersection to work you will need to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()`.

https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts

But internally `Module` will check for equality using `equals` and `hascode`, if not provided then from Object class.....
Overall for your requirement to work you will need to implement `equals()` and `hashcode()` in all your 3 classes, `Result`, `Module` and `TestCase`.